# Is there a way to convert key and value of input JSON to seperate rows in JSON using JOLT?

Tags: jolt

Is there a way to get the expected output with JOLT?

InputJSON :

```
{
 k1:v1
}
```

Expected JSON  :

```
{ 
name : k1, 
value: v1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` match all, `@` is the key, and `$` is the value.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "name",
        "$": "value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```